# Is there any way to add or remove UI elements completely?

Tags: wii-u, monster-hunter-3-ultimate

With the release of the new Monster Hunter on Wii U, they've added in the ability to customize the gamepad with specific UI items, such as your health and stamina bars, the map, etc.  Doing so automatically removes them from the UI on the TV.  In fact, the default layout removes every bit of UI from the TV, allowing you to just see the gorgeous graphics themselves.

This customization is fairly easy to figure out and arrange on the gamepad.  The problem is that once you remove it from the gamepad, it automatically pops up on the TV again.  I don't want that.  I want to pull the specific element off of the TV, *and* off of the gamepad.  I don't want it visible anywhere.

As a secondary, but related problem, is there a way to display the same element on both the TV and the gamepad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much easier way. If you want the UI elements off of the gamepad AND the TV, such as the map for example, there are options in the menu to hide them. Just hit minus, then go to options, and there should be an option to hide the map and other UI elements completely. That way they wont clutter up the screen or the gamepad! Happy hunting!

As for displaying on both, I dont think it's possible...

Comment: I'll have to try this this weekend.

Comment: works great for me because I dont really use the map all that much, and it takes up too much space on the gamepad, so I just kinda blip it out of existence! :)

Answer (score -1):

The only way to remove all UI elements from the Screen is by putting them on the gamepad, and disabling the ZR/ZL functionality in the in-game options.

If you go to Options -> Game Settings (or page 3 of the ingame options), You can change the Wii U Gamepad Option to Type 2 to have the same image on the screen as well as the gamepad. (You will need to do this each time you start the game.)

This will **NOT** restore the UI elements you have placed on the gamepad, effectively removing them completely.

Comment: This eliminates everything on the touch panel, though; that's not really what I'm after.